# datatable table.rows.add not working

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

Good Day

I am trying to add rows to datatable using jquery.
table.rows.add(['Andani']).draw();

The added string "Andani" is being split across for columns.
You will get the "A" in the first column, "n" in the second column, "d" in the third column, and so on an so on.

What could I be doing wrong?

I have `<th class="SideTables">ContactName</th>` now I have left the <`tbody></tbody>` empty to be amended by jquery. I have now factored `table.rows.add([{"ContactName":"Andani"}]).draw();` however this time around the table is blank.

Comment: Just `add([...])` with the correct number of columns, i.e   `table.rows.add(['Andani', '', '', ''])` (so it adds up with the amount of columns)

Answer (score 0):

Datatables `rows.add()` method will sure split it to columns if you **only** give it **a string**.

What you should do is to give the string with *column names*.

Lets assume you have columns;

- Name
- Surname
- Age
- Company

Your `rows.add()` method should be like this;

```
table.rows.add([{
        "Name": "Emre",
        "Surname": "Bolat",
        "Age": "30",
        "Company": "ABC XYZ"
    }, {
        "Name": "Andi",
        "Surname": "Masikhwa",
        "Age": "??",
        "Company": "???"
    }]).draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Emre.  the table I have is <th class="SideTables">ContactName</th> now I have left the <tbody></tbody> empty to be amended by jquery.  I have now factored you reply into my code to make it look like this table.rows.add([{"ContactName":"Andani"}]).draw(); however this time around the table is blank.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post your code?